# Cannot access process object in react and non-node js backend (apache) server application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apache, babeljs

I'm working on a react tutorial, however we are not using node js as the backend server.  We are however using `babel` and `webpack` and `react`, but `apache` with a `custom php backend`.

Because of this, as far as i have researched, we do not have access to the process object because its a node internal object?

```
const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
```

This seems like a **crucial object** that is neccessary for react development but like i said im just a novice so i dont know the answer.

**How do we gain access to this object or if not whats our backup plan as i've seen this process object in other react code ive looked at and i want to make sure its available before we start getting heavy into development**

Answer (score 1):

The `process` object is something specific to Node but its usage is widely used with Webpack to provide environment variable. By default Webpack [creates a polyfill](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node) for the `process` object.

To create your own variable you can use the Webpak plugin [EnvironmentPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/).